# Is it possible to hide Mediawiki redirect pages from showing in Special:AllPages?

Tags: mediawiki

Is it possible to hide redirect pages from showing in Special:AllPages when linked to in the sidebar? They currently are displayed *italicized*, which is the default.

Comment: Check the "Hide redirects" checkbox?

Comment: @Tgr Yes, thank you. BTW, that was possibly the worst worded question I've ever typed. I just edited the question for proper context.

Comment: The answer is still the same though (well, check the box, submit the form, copy that URL to the sidebar).

Comment: @Tgr Again, thanks. I had tried using regular wiki markup to create a link, but that didn't produce the desired results. The format is special to that `MediaWiki:Sidebar` page. Using `** //example.com/w/index.php?title=Special%3AAllPages&from=&to=&namespace=0&hideredirects=1|All wiki pages` did the trick.

Comment: @Paul can you add that as answer, then, please?

Comment: @Nemo I added it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To make the link to 'All Wiki Pages' in the sidebar display all pages but without redirects, navigate to www.example.com/w/MediaWiki:Sidebar and change:

```
** Special:AllPages|All Wiki Pages
```

to

```
** //www.example.com/w/index.php?title=Special%3AAllPages&from=&to=&namespace=0&hidered‌​irects=1|All Wiki Pages
```